# How to read dicom tag value using openDicom.net in C#?

Tags: c#, tags, dicom

I'm reading dicom tags using openDicom.net like this:

```
string tag = "";
string description = "";
string val_rep = "";

foreach (DataElement elementy in sq)
{
    tag = elementy.Tag.ToString();
    description = elementy.VR.Tag.GetDictionaryEntry().Description;
    val_rep = elementy.VR.ToString();
}
```

How can I read dicom tag values?

Comment: why did this get downvoted?  It's a legit question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that sq is a Sequence...

I've not worked with openDicom, but I'm pretty sure what you're doing there isn't going to yield the results you want.

You have a single tag, description, and val_rep variable, but you're filling them using a foreach, meaning the last DataElement in the Sequence will be the only values you retrieve. You would achieve the same effect by using:

```
string tag = sq[sq.Count - 1].Tag.ToString();
string description = sq[sq.Count -1].VR.Tag.GetDictionaryEntry().Description;
string val_rep = sq[sq.Count - 1].VR.ToString();
```

Thus retrieving the last set of values from the Sequence. I believe you'll find that if you step through the foreach as it executes, it will be loading all the different DataElements contained in your DICOM file.

Feel free to return a comment or post more information in your original post if I'm way off base here.

Comment: Your code doesn't read any tag.My code read the same things like another viewers,but i can't find how to show tag value.

Comment: As you step through your foreach, does val_rep get loaded with other values? My point is that even though you're using a foreach on the Sequence's DataElements, you're still only going to RETURN the values from the final DataElement from the Sequence. That final DataElement could very well be empty.

Comment: @Nathan Wheeler No idea why this was marked as the correct answer. luc is asking how you get the value of the tag. It appears that all of the members that would lead you to the value are private.

Answer (score 1):

the `value.ToString()` method isn't implemented. Implement your own method in Value.cs and you will get a value for "Value".

For example (only strings and numeric values):

```
public override string ToString()
{
 return valueList[0].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The tag value is retrieved as an array of generic object from the 'Value' member in 'DataElement' using the 'ToArray()' overriding method in the 'Value' class.

```
cniDicomTagList = new List<CNIDicomTag>();
foreach (DataElement element in sq)
{
     string tag = element.Tag.ToString();
     string description = element.VR.Tag.GetDictionaryEntry().Description;
     object[] valueArr = element.Value.ToArray();
     cniDicomTagList.Add(new CNIDicomTag(tag, description, valueArr));
}
```